# Magento cannot update products and categories from admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Not able to edit and update the products from magento admin. While trying to save the product I am getting the following error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Object::addData() must
>   be of the type array, null given, called in
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
>   on line 513 and defined in ../public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on
>   line 243

It was working fine few days back and stopped working all of sudden.

Answer (score 1):

Please clear the cache.
It may solve your problem. 
If you have Compilation enabled than disable it and then clear and disable cache. Then try again.

It may help you.